# Yii2 display multiple values from one relation in GridView

Tags: search, yii2

I did my grid by the this instruction http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/653/displaying-sorting-and-filtering-model-relations-on-a-gridview/
and it worked. But now I need to have two columns with data related to one column. For example in person/index the gridView must display cityName and cityRegion from the related record in the City table.

I managed to display the data, but can't get the search functionality working.

In the example from the link, at the end of the function search() there is

```
$query->andFilterWhere([
    //... other searched attributes here
])
// Here we search the attributes of our relations using our previously configured
// ones in "TourSearch"
->andFilterWhere(['like', 'tbl_city.name', $this->city])
->andFilterWhere(['like', 'tbl_country.name', $this->country]);
```

I think I should have something like:

```
->andFilterWhere(['like', 'tbl_city.name', $this->city])
->andFilterWhere(['like', 'tbl_city.region', $this->city])
```

...but I don't know how to get the actual search values for (in this case name and region).

Thanks!

EDIT*
Here is the whole search() and rules definition: http://pastebin.com/mUVDYNiH
Currently the sorting of prod_ProductCode and prod_Manufacturer is working, but the search boxes for them doesn't show up.

Comment: post your whole `search()`.

Answer (score 0):

Check here [yii2 ActiveQuery 'OR LIKE' filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28592805/yii2-activequery-or-like-filter):

$query->andFilterWhere([
    'or',
    ['like', 'tbl_city.name', $this->city],
    ['like', 'tbl_city.region', $this->city],
]);