# Yii2 passing an array in the FilterWhere Condition

Tags: yii2, yii2-basic-app, yii2-model

I'm trying to pass array elements in the filter where condition.

**getFacilityID() function**

```
 public function getFacilityID()
    {
        $facArray= array();

        $facilityName = Facility::find()->where(['company_id' => \Yii::$app->user->identity->company_id])->all();
        foreach ($facilityName as $facName){
            $facArray[] = $facName->facility_id;
        }  
         //   var_dump($facArray); exit();
            return $facArray;


    }
```

Here I'm filtering using the **getFacilityID()** function

```
 $query->orFilterWhere(['like', 'area_name', $this->area_name])
                ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'facility_id', $this->getfacilityID()]);
```

The issue is if i have more than 1 facilities it doesn't display any areas.

**"->andFilterWhere(['like', 'facility_id', $this->getfacilityID()]); "**

The code in bold is causing the issue, if the getfacilityId() has more than 1 array element it doesn't display data in areas. If there is only one element in getFacilityId() it displays the data correctly. Can I get the solution for this??

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [yii2 ActiveQuery 'OR LIKE' filter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28592805/yii2-activequery-or-like-filter)

Comment: You can't use `like` with arrays hence the possible duplicate.

Comment: Thanks Buddy... got it solved!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As **Topher** mentioned cannot use arrays with like. So changed the query to In condition which worked.

```
 $query->orFilterWhere(['like', 'area_name', $this->area_name])     
        ->andFilterWhere(['in', 'facility_id', $this->getFacilityID()]);
```

Read more: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-queryinterface.html#where()-detail

Answer (score 2):

try this code:

```
        if(null != $this->getFacilityID())
            foreach ($this->getfacilityID() as $key => $id) {
                $query->orFilterWhere(['like', 'facility_id', $id]);
            }
        $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'area_name', $this->area_name]);
        $query->all();
```

Here is my example

```
        foreach (['a1','b1'] as $key => $value) {
            $q->orFilterWhere(['like', 'username', $value]);
        }
        $q->andFilterWhere(['like', 'email', 'someEmail']);
        $q->all();
```

**and  result query is :**

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    `user`
WHERE
    ((`username` LIKE '%a1%')
        OR (`username` LIKE '%b1%'))
        AND (`email` LIKE '%someEmail%')
```

Comment: Can you explain your example clearly? It would be helpful and thank you very much.

Comment: @MohanPrasad look at last section with result `sql` query if it is what you looking for (ignore different columns names ) then just  grab first code section from answer and test it yourself

Comment: That works great!!!!  So using foreach you can loop the elements and pass it on to the like condition!! but it breaks the code when I have no facilities created. but anyways i have an alternative solution. Thanks very much!!

Comment: @MohanPrasad of course it will break, usually you should to check if getfacilityID() is empty and skip this logic

Comment: @in my  way  or else ?

Comment: Yep just put the foreach inside a if statement. if(!getFacilityID() == null)

Comment: @MohanPrasad updated the code. So if it slowed your problem then choose as answer )

Comment: I am using a different solution. I have used my answer which I have answered to this question.

Comment: The same issue, if I have more than 1 facilities it doesn't display the areas.

Comment: @MohanPrasad lets move to chat discuss it

Comment: I have only 18 reputations, so cannot move to chat, I think i need 20..

Comment: @MohanPrasad now it should be enough )

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117319/discussion-between-mohan-prasad-and--).